# multithreading using tcplistener

Tags: c#

I wrote the below code to get a string (encrypted) from the user, and I need to use a thread.

```
        TcpListener TCPListen = new TcpListener(IP2, port);

        TCPListen.Start();


        TcpClient TCP = TCPListen.AcceptTcpClient();


        NetworkStream NetStream = TCP.GetStream();





        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();


        byte[] Key = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
        byte[] IV = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };




        CryptoStream CryptStream = new CryptoStream(NetStream,
           RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),
           CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader(CryptStream);
```

Ihe problem is that i should use the thread after the TCPListen.Start(); otherwise will get an error**(Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted)**
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: so I think you want to accept the client connection, and then move the TcpClient work to another thread allowing the main thread to accept another client.  Is that right?

Comment: This is described fairly well on MSDN.  You may want to look there; this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706117/socket-programming/706154#706154) is also very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to moving the blocking calls to a new thread, you can use use BeginConnect, BeginReceive, BeginSend methods and their corresponding End(Connect | Receive | Send) as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=VS.100).aspx).

EDIT: RE: question below from OP...
Instead of calling `Connect()`, you would call `BeginConnect()` and provide `BeginConnect()` a method to call when someone connects (known as a "Callback").  This Callback will get called so that you can do whatever work you need to do.  The first thing your code should do is call `EndConnect()`.  The issue is that calling `Connect()` blocks (ie, halts all code execution on that thread) until it returns.  Using the `BeginXXX()` and `EndXXX()` side steps this issue.  Its really too meaty of a topic to explain in any useful depth here.  Study at the MSDN doc linked above.  If you have specific questions after spending some time with it, post them back here and I'll try to answer them.  :)

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set-up one listener per port as requests to connect are queued and then assigned their own TCP client. You can see the link below for more informaion but essentially you shouldn't be trying to attach multiple listeners and I don't think a new thread will let you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx